# imagegrabwindow error on wamp server

Tags: php, com, screenshot, wamp

I'm trying to take screenshot using imagegrabwindow function. But it occurs warnings and doesn't save the image. Here is my code and output. Does anybody know how can i solve this problem?

Note: I changed apache service setting (Allow service to interact with desktop) as checked.

```
<?php
 $browser = new COM("InternetExplorer.Application");
 $handle = $browser->HWND;
 $browser->Visible = true;
 $browser->Navigate("http://www.brove.net");

 /* Still working? */
 while ($browser->Busy) {
    com_message_pump(4000);
 }
 $im = imagegrabwindow($handle, 0);
 $browser->Quit();
 imagepng($im, "iesnap.png");
 imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

[image]

Comment: I'm getting this error on WAMP server as well. Did you resolve the issue?

Comment: I couldnt solve this problem. I setup CutyCapt to my server. Then take screenshot with using shell_exec function.

Comment: I work on same subject and managed to work it on Xamp but getting black images sometimes. Did you success to work it and have you ever come across black image problem?